# Why is the size of a word limited?

Tags: algorithms, books

In Chapter 23 of CLRS, the following quote appears:

> We also assume a limit on the size of each word of data. 
>   For example, when working with inputs of size $n$, we typically assume that integers are represented by $c \lg n$ bits, for some constant $c ≥ 1$.

Here is how I understand the text:
I searched on the Internet about what does a word of data means. Turns out that a word of data is a data unit used by processors. Different processors have different definitions on a word of data. For example, processor A takes 16 bit as a word of data while processor B takes 24. I think of a word of data as a box, placed in the RAM. We assume a limit of the size of whatever inside the box.

I am so worried about if my understanding is wrong, as I have a strong feeling that it is. The problem is I can't seem to find a better explanation of the text than this one.

Comment: Your text is missing some context...

Comment: See here: https://www.quora.com/In-CLRS-what-does-the-text-We-also-assume-a-limit-on-the-size-of-each-word-of-data-For-example-when-working-with-inputs-of-size-n-we-typically-assume-that-integers-are-represented-by-c-lg-n-bits-for-some-constant-c-%E2%89%A5-1-mean.